# Unable to switch to WebView context on iOS Appium test (AWS Device Farm)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, webview, appium

I'm using AWS Device farm, and I'm running an Appium Java TestNG test on an hybrid Cordova app (iOS), which contains a WebView, but when I get the available contexts, there's only "NATIVE_APP".

After some research, I've found that you have to launch ios-webkit-debug-proxy to be able to switch contexts on real devices, but I also read that it is automatically launched on AWS Device Farm iOS tests.

When I run the test, the Appium Server Output shows this:

> ***[iOS] Attempted to get a list of webview contexts but could not connect to ios-webkit-debug-proxy. If you expect to find webviews, please ensure that the proxy is running and accessible***

Is there any additional configuration needed in order to be able to switch contexts on iOS? If not, does anyone know what can be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appium 1.6.3 or above is compatible with iOS 10 on device farm.

The issue you pointed out seems to be a recurring issue as noticed on the Appium forums.

The ios-webkit-debug-proxy is automatically launched on device farm.

We are currently in the process of deploying support for Hybrid apps which will enable you to run apps based on Cordova.
Right now the support is only for native apps.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The Appium support for hybrid iOS 10 apps on device farm is crucial for me right now. So I'd like to be informed as soon as it's working. Where would I need to go to get news on this topic? For example is there a github issue I could follow? Or maybe you could notify us here on completion?

Comment: We are still facing the same issue. Is the support for hybrid apps already there? It is mentioned in the official doc that Hybrid apps are supported in  [AWS device farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/)

Comment: Hybrid apps are supported for iOS 10/11 on Device Farm.